# Tcl regsub substitute other character to another for all alphapets

Tags: tcl

I need to generate a random output string of same length given an original string. I was trying the below method:

```
regsub -all  -nocase ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUYWXYZ0123456789 ZYXWYUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA9876543210 $str
```

But the output is always irrespective of what values variable str has:

```
ZYXWYUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA9876543210
```

My requirement is to substitute or replace something like A to Z , B to Y .... 0 to 9 and 9 to 0?
How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`string map`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/string.htm#M34):

```
# Just generating the replacements, we want to have "A Z B Y C X ... 0 9 ... 9 0"
set letters "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUYWXYZ"
set numbers "0123456789"
set replacements {}

foreach l [split $letters ""] r [split [string reverse $letters] ""] {
    lappend replacements $l $r
}

foreach n [split $numbers ""] r [split [string reverse $numbers] ""] {
    lappend replacements $n $r
}

# string map in use:
set input "MEW2"
set output [string map -nocase $replacements $input]
# NYD7
```

---

The issue with regsub is that you cannot easily tell it to replace something that maps to something specific, you'd have to create a separate procedure and make further substitutions. To keep things simple, just use string map which is made for this kind of substitution.

Comment: It'll be a lot easier to use `regsub` in 8.7, but `string map` will continue to be my favoured approach for this stuff.